# Div inline-block vertical alignment?

Tags: html, css

When running https://jsfiddle.net/8vy5aefr/2/ at a `width` of around 220px, is there a way for the blue square to sit right underneath the red square (aside from margin-top:-100px;)?

> Note the single column "mobile" mode at around 100px is displaying as desired: red, green, blue.)

```
.d1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have your CSS properties with first-letter caps?

Comment: Please explain clearly about the question

Comment: @RahulDesai Apologies - just free-coding from this iPad with its auto capitalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Wrapped all divs in One parent div and gave `float:right` to `.d2`

```css
.wrapper {
  width:100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.d1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
}
.d2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: right;
}
.d3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  vertical-align: top;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width:201px){
  .d1,.d2,.d3{
    float:none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='d1'></div>
  <div class='d2'></div>
  <div class='d3'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but float:right doesn't align green under red as the window width is dragged wider.

Comment: You can use media queries to achieve this.

Comment: yeah thought it could possibly lead there as the easiest/simplest way. Thanks for the efforts all the same.

Comment: I have updated answer, please check once. Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8vy5aefr/5/

Answer (score 2):

Try this: add `clear:both; float:left;` in `.d3` and `float:left;` in `.d1`.

```css
.d1
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
display: inline-block;
background-color:red;
vertical-align:top;
float:left;
}

.d2
{
width:100px;
height:200px;
display: inline-block;
background-color:green;
vertical-align:top;
}

.d3
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
display: inline-block;
background-color:blue;
vertical-align:top;
clear:both; float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class='d1'></div>
<div class='d2'></div>
<div class='d3'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks though didn't work on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oc6nkf01/1/ when width was around 210px

Comment: @user1946932 then you can create a parent div and put them inside and assign the `max-width :200px; ` to the parent div.

Comment: use `clear:left` instead of `clear:both;` and since the parent width is exact to the sum of children width force green div to ` float :right`. but it will be good to write media queries instead of these changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
.d3{
    Width: 100px;
    Height: 100px;
    Display: inline-block;
    Background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    position: initial;
    clear: both;
}
.d2 {
    Width: 100px;
    Height: 200px;
    Display: inline-block;
    Background-color: green;

}

.d1 {
    Width: 100px;
    Height: 100px;
    Display: inline-block;
    Background-color: red;
    Vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}

This will help you
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine using `table` instead DIV then here is the simple code.

```css
.d1 {
  Width: 100px;
  Height: 100px;
  Background-color: red;
}
.d2 {
  Width: 100px;
  Height: 200px;
  Background-color: green;
}
.d3 {
  Width: 100px;
  Height: 100px;
  Background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="d1">Red</td>
    <td class="d2" rowspan="2">Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="d3">Blue</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```